# Save github logs to file

Tags: github, github-api, github-for-windows

Is it possible to save github commits (info about commit, branch, author etc.) to file and create graph with branches as image?
I don't want to make repository public, but I need to share my progress without giving access to repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you're looking for, but using the git commands you can do that sort of thing. Clone the repo on your machine, `cd` to the repo, then you can do something like :

```
$ git log --graph --decorate --glob="*"
```

See screenshot below.

[image]

If you don't need to do this from a script, you can just copy-paste the terminal output. Otherwise, I'm sure there's a way to place it all into a file.

This graphical output is, IMO, quite useful. I personally use `git hist` as an alias of the verbose command above.

Comment: + That's what I was looking for

Comment: Do you know any tool to create equivalent image in .jpg or ,png format?

Comment: @AleksanderBurzec Unfortunately, no. Sorry.

Comment: I found a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24107223/6843123
Edit: Nope, for static input only.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best solution I found, git log output as HTML file:
https://github.com/bluef/gitgraph.js
Anyway, @Anthony D. provided pretty simple and clean solution.